# CakePHP 3.4 DebugKit won't request via TLS behind AWS load balancer

Tags: cakephp, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cakephp-debug-kit

I'm running my webapp on AWS Elastic Beanstalk on instances behind a load balancer.  I terminate HTTPS at the load balancer as per [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html).

Apache is set to rewrite any inbound http requests to https via this directive: `<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>`

Additionally, I'm using CakePHP's security component to redirect any connections without the X-Forwarded-Proto https header onto secure connections.

Despite this, my app is still requesting non-secure DebugKit assets, and the server is responding in the clear.  This is causing Internet Explorer not to run the DebugKit scripts because they are not secure content.  I've disabled mixed content protections in IE, but that hasn't allowed DebugKit to run.

Ultimately, I'd prefer to serve everything securely rather than resort to a client-side workaround.  Any suggestions?  What am I missing?

Comment: What's the value of `Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl')` when you're invoking your site via `https`?

Comment: it's showing http, not https.  I think that's because the load balancer is communicating in to the instances behind it in the clear.  All of my other assets are being served back via https, but not the DebugKit

Comment: You other assets are probably served using relative paths (debug kit is embedded via an iframe using an absolute URL)? Try hardcoding the `App.fullBaseUrl` config value to use `https`, if PHP doesn't know about the HTTPS state, then there isn't much you can do I guess. [**Check your `config/bootstrap.php` file**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.4.2/config/bootstrap.php#L132-L149).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer over at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805437/cakephp-absolute-urls-for-loginaction).  Basically, I can either edit cake/bootstrap.php to look for X-Forwarded-Proto, or use .extensions to manually set the HTTPS server var on.